# Angular js error in date format

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I have an input type html element where the date format is `mm/dd/yyyy`.

[image]I coded the whole app, in the server,executing through ionic serve.  Now when i installed the app on mobile, the date format of the input type is set as `yyyy/mm/dd`.Can anyone tell me what to do in this situation?Sorry couldn't provide any plunker.

The code is:

```
<div class="row"> 
    <div class="col-50 padd_5">
        <label class="item item-input">Date:</label>
        <input type="date" placeholder="Enter Date" ng-model="createEventForm.date" name="eventDate" required>
         <br />
         <div ng-show="eventFormObject.$submitted || eventFormObject.eventDate.$touched">
             <div ng-show="eventFormObject.eventDate.$invalid">Event date is invalid.</div>
         </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Note:This question is not a dublicate of [Is there any way to change input type="date" format?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7372038/is-there-any-way-to-change-input-type-date-format) as no data for mobile input type date view is given,only html5

Comment: Where is the code for it.?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there any way to change input type="date" format?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7372038/is-there-any-way-to-change-input-type-date-format)

Comment: This post will help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7372038/is-there-any-way-to-change-input-type-date-format

Comment: @Rhumborl the question is not dublicate as no data for mobile input type date view is given,only html5

Comment: that's irrelevant, it's still how to display an `<input type="date">` in a browser, whether that's on mobile, desktop or otherwise - it's the same ("html5") element

Comment: @Rhumborl so you are saying that there is no way to change the default html date format?i then can do the changes.But the problem will then arise that i cannot test with ionic serve as well as in the mobile as both of them have different input type date default format?

Comment: @Rhumborl server->mm/dd/yyyy ; mobile->yyyy/mm/dd. these are the default formats.If there is nothing i can do but to test for only one form factor i.e. mobile then i will close this question as answered.Give me your opinion

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After checking @Rhumborl's comments , i came to the conclusion that date format for html5 cannot be changed.It paves way for a rather awkward situation that the default date format for server is mm/dd/yyyy and for mobile it is yyyy/mm/dd.Anyways thanks for your time who commented.